# How to calculate percent similarity between two sets of compositional data

Tags: probability, distributions, python, similarities, compositional-data

I have data that is in the form:

```
data1=[0.03510584946878486, 0.09929433687476773, 0.049647168437383864, 0.03510584946878486, 0.01755292473439243, 0.07021169893756972, 0.07021169893756972, 0.024823584218691932, 0.03510584946878486, 0.01755292473439243, 0.024823584218691932, 0.2808467957502789, 0.03510584946878486, 0.01755292473439243, 0.03510584946878486, 0.049647168437383864, 0.03510584946878486, 0.01755292473439243, 0.024823584218691932, 0.024823584218691932]
data2=[0.036891382048211505, 0.29513105638569204, 0.05217229282726804, 0.02608614641363402, 0.018445691024105752, 0.07378276409642301, 0.05217229282726804, 0.02608614641363402, 0.05217229282726804, 0.018445691024105752, 0.02608614641363402, 0.10434458565453608, 0.036891382048211505, 0.018445691024105752, 0.02608614641363402, 0.036891382048211505, 0.036891382048211505, 0.018445691024105752, 0.02608614641363402, 0.018445691024105752]
```

These individual elements are probabilities that sum to 1.0, but instead of being classical intervalic measurements (as represented by a histogram for example), these are compositional data (as represented by a bar graph for example). My understanding is that to calculate how similar the two data are, I can't use the Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic or Jensen-Shannon distance. The Aitchison distance might be what I'm looking for (although I've been getting division-by-zero issues).

My general question is: how does one calculate the percent similarity between these two probability "distributions" when the data is compositional?  It would be very helpful if someone could point to a python implementation.

Comment: You may want to look into the description document of "Various proximities" collection on my web-page. In the description on of macro !proxqnt, there, among other, are formulas of most popular similarity measures for compositional vectors ("probability vectors")

Comment: What do you mean by 'percent similarity between these two probability distributions'?
What's the 'percent' part about? Besides that, why not use KL Divergence, which is a common way of measuring distance between two probability distributions, with many implementations in python.

Comment: @piotrwiercinski The percent similarity flavour is perhaps explained by reading my answer, as the measure there varies from 0 to 1 and is often reported in percent terms. Even then it strictly measures percent dissimilarity unless you take its complement in 1 or 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One measure is variously known; I think I first encountered it as *dissimilarity index*, but watch out as that name is certainly generic as well as specific. The recipe is for dissimilarity between $j$ and $k$ over proportions in categories $i$

$$ (1/2) \sum_i | p_{i, j} - p_{i,k} | $$

where the prefactor $(1/2)$ scales the result to lie in $[0, 1]$. Two identical profiles yield $0$. Here is an easy example of the other extreme: suppose every beast in Freedonia is an elephant and every beast in Sylvania is an aardvark. Then the sum is, apart from many terms $|0 - 0|$, $$|1 - 0| + |0 - 1| = 2$$ and halving scales the maximum to $1$.

Comment: This is a straightforward solution, thanks! I will take the complement to get a similarity.